# Conectar MySQL a express

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo un servidor con MySQL y express pero no puedo conectarme con el servidor. Intente lo siguiente:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection=mysql.createConnection({
host:"localhost",
user:"pedro",
password:"cocoypaco2",
database:"users",
```

});
connection.connect();
y el error que me tira la consola a la hora de abrir el servidor es:
ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE:

La version que tengo de MySQL es 8.0.13
GRACIAS!

Comment: tienes dos opciones: la primera o usas una versión inferior a mysql 8, o la segunda lo reinstalas y donde diga que tipo de conexión eliges la que indique legacy; para que soporte el modo de cifrado anterior al que se implementó en mysql 8

Comment: Creo que tienes razón Shadow, el problema es que no me deja desinstalar el mysql server 8.0 para reinstalar el viejo, por que cuando modifico desde el installer no se guarda lo que cambio o por lo menos no hace efecto...